# Is this LINQ Query "correct"?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

I have the following LINQ query, that is returning the results that I expect, but it does not "feel" right.

Basically it is a left join.  I need ALL records from the UserProfile table.

Then the LastWinnerDate is a single record from the winner table (possible multiple records) indicating the DateTime the last record was entered in that table for the user.

WinnerCount is the number of records for the user in the winner table (possible multiple records).

Video1 is basically a bool indicating there is, or is not a record for the user in the winner table matching on a third table Objective (should be 1 or 0 rows).

Quiz1 is same as Video 1 matching another record from Objective Table (should be 1 or 0 rows).

Video and Quiz is repeated 12 times because it is for a report to be displayed to a user listing all user records and indicate if they have met the objectives.

```
var objectiveIds = new List<int>();
objectiveIds.AddRange(GetObjectiveIds(objectiveName, false));

var q =
    from up in MetaData.UserProfile
    select new RankingDTO
    {
        UserId = up.UserID,
        FirstName = up.FirstName,
        LastName = up.LastName,
        LastWinnerDate = (
            from winner in MetaData.Winner
            where objectiveIds.Contains(winner.ObjectiveID)
            where winner.Active
            where winner.UserID == up.UserID
            orderby winner.CreatedOn descending
            select winner.CreatedOn).First(),
        WinnerCount = (
            from winner in MetaData.Winner
            where objectiveIds.Contains(winner.ObjectiveID)
            where winner.Active
            where winner.UserID == up.UserID
            orderby winner.CreatedOn descending
            select winner).Count(),
        Video1 = (
            from winner in MetaData.Winner
            join o in MetaData.Objective on winner.ObjectiveID equals o.ObjectiveID
            where o.ObjectiveNm == Constants.Promotions.SecVideo1
            where winner.Active
            where winner.UserID == up.UserID
            select winner).Count(),
        Quiz1 = (
            from winner2 in MetaData.Winner
            join o2 in MetaData.Objective on winner2.ObjectiveID equals o2.ObjectiveID
            where o2.ObjectiveNm == Constants.Promotions.SecQuiz1
            where winner2.Active
            where winner2.UserID == up.UserID
            select winner2).Count(),
    };
```

Comment: what part doesn't _feel right_ =)

Comment: Try a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How I'm accomplishing the left joins.  I'm still learning LINQ, and in T-SQL I would just write the JOINS in the main part of the Query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeating `join winners table` part several times. In order to avoid it you can break it into several consequent `Selects`. So instead of having one huge select, you can make two selects with lesser code. In your example I would first of all select `winner2` variable before selecting other result properties:

```
var q1 =
    from up in MetaData.UserProfile
    select new {up, 
                winners = from winner in MetaData.Winner
                         where winner.Active
                         where winner.UserID == up.UserID
                         select winner};
var q = from upWinnerPair in q1
    select new RankingDTO
    {
        UserId = upWinnerPair.up.UserID,
        FirstName = upWinnerPair.up.FirstName,
        LastName = upWinnerPair.up.LastName,
        LastWinnerDate = /* Here you will have more simple and less repeatable code 
                           using winners collection from "upWinnerPair.winners"*/
```

Comment: this will not select any user records that do not also have winner records.  I need to perform an outer join to retrieve ALL user records regardless of if they have winner records or not.

Comment: @Schenz, you can still extract outer join into first statement. The idea remains the same.

Comment: I'm trying to see it, but I'm still learning LINQ, and it is not obvious to me yet...

Comment: @Schenz, see my updated answer. From the first query you will receive a pairs of **1)** `up` object itself **2)** left joined `winners` for this `up`

Comment: That looks so much better, and is alot easier to read.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The query itself is pretty simple: just a main outer query and a series of subselects to retrieve actual column data. While it's not the most efficient means of querying the data you're after (joins and using windowing functions will likely get you better performance), it's the only real way to represent that query using either the query or expression syntax (windowing functions in SQL have no mapping in LINQ or the LINQ-supporting extension methods).

Note that you aren't doing any actual outer joins (left or right) in your code; you're creating subqueries to retrieve the column data. It might be worth looking at the actual SQL being generated by your query. You don't specify which ORM you're using (which would determine how to examine it client-side) or which database you're using (which would determine how to examine it server-side).

If you're using the ADO.NET Entity Framework, you can cast your query to an `ObjectQuery` and call `ToTraceString()`.

If you're using SQL Server, you can use SQL Server Profiler (assuming you have access to it) to view the SQL being executed, or you can run a trace manually to do the same thing.

To perform an outer join in LINQ query syntax, do this:

Assuming we have two sources `alpha` and `beta`, each having a common `Id` property, you can select from `alpha` and perform a left join on `beta` in this way:

```
from a in alpha
join btemp in beta on a.Id equals btemp.Id into bleft
from b in bleft.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new { IdA = a.Id, IdB = b.Id }
```

Admittedly, the syntax is a little oblique. Nonetheless, it works and will be translated into something like this in SQL:

```
select
    a.Id as IdA,
    b.Id as Idb

from alpha a

left join beta b on a.Id = b.Id
```

Comment: @Schenz: It looks like LLBL outputs generated SQL using the .NET tracing mechanism. You can implement a simple `TraceListener` class and monitor the SQL from that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me, though I could see why the multiple sub-queries could trigger inefficiency worries in the eyes of a coder.

Take a look at what SQL is produced though (I'm guessing you're running this against a database source from your saying "table" above), before you start worrying about that. The query providers can be pretty good at producing nice efficient SQL that in turn produces a good underlying database query, and if that's happening, then happy days (it will also give you another view on being sure of the correctness).